# Complete subset of $X$ such that elements are of a fixed norm value implies $X$ Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I am doing the exercise 5 in section 5.2 of Naylor's Linear Operator Theory in Engineering and Science.

> Let $(X, ||·||)$ be a normed linear space and let $S_r = \{x ∈ X : ||x|| = r\}$
>   where $r > 0$. Assume that $X \neq \{0\}.$ Show that $(X, || · ||)$ is a Banach space if and only if $(S_r, || · ||)$ is
>   complete for some $r > 0$.

The left to right proof is easy enough. However, I'm having trouble proving right to left. In fact, I think it's incorrect. As a counterexample, let $X$ be the rationals over the field of rationals with the usual absolute value norm. This should be indeed a normed linear space.

Fix $r$>0. So $S_r$ should just be $\{-r,r\}$. Here, the Cauchy sequences are the ones that are eventually constant. These clearly converge to either $-r$ or $r$. Hence $S_r$ is complete, but $X$, the rationals, is not Banach.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: As pointed out, my counterexample fails since my space must be over the reals or the complex numbers. This still leaves me at a roadblock. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The base field is usually fixed to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Isn't it done in the present case?

Comment: Do you make any assumptions on $X$? Finite dimensional space ? Norm derived from an inner product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose that $(S_r, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is complete and consider a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$. $(x_n)$ is bounded.

If $(x_n)$ converges to $0$, we are done. So we can suppose that $(x_n)$ doesn’t converge to $0$. This implies that it exists $d >0$ and a subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ such that $\Vert x_{\varphi(n)}\Vert \ge d$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

As $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, it exists $L \in \mathbb N$ such that for $s,t \ge L$ $\Vert x_s-x_t \Vert \le d/4$. Fix $m$ such that $M=\varphi(m) \ge L$. For $s \ge M$ $x_s$ belongs to the closed ball $B$ centered on $x_M$ of radius $d/4$.

Now $(\frac{r}{\Vert x_s \Vert})_{s \ge M}$ is a real sequence which is Cauchy. Hence converges to $l >0$. For $s,t \ge M$, you have

$$\begin{aligned}\left\Vert \frac{r}{\Vert x_s \Vert}x_s -\frac{r}{\Vert x_t \Vert}x_t  \right\Vert &= \left\Vert \left(\frac{r}{\Vert x_s \Vert}x_s - l x_s\right) + (lx_s - l x_t)  -\left(\frac{r}{\Vert x_s \Vert}x_s - l x_s\right) \right\Vert\\
& \le \left(\left\Vert x_s\right\Vert + \left\Vert x_s\right\Vert\right)\left\vert 
 \frac{r}{\Vert x_s \Vert} - l  \right\vert + l \Vert x_s - x_t \Vert
\end{aligned}$$

Inequality that you can use to prove that the sequence $(r \frac{x_s}{\Vert x_s \Vert})_{s\ge M}$ is a Cauchy sequence of $S_r$. That converges under the hypothesis that $S_r$ is complete.

Conclude by proving that this implies that $(x_s)_{s \ge M}$ converges.

Comment: I'm confused to whether $r$ is the index of the Cauchy sequence in $S_r$, or the $r$ in the hypothesis.

Comment: @HCS Good point. I updated variable names.

Comment: I can get where the proof is going, but showing $(r \frac{x_s}{\Vert x_s \Vert})_{s\ge M}$ is Cauchy is giving me trouble. I want to add and subtract the terms $\frac{x_M}{\Vert x_s \Vert}$ and $\frac{x_M}{\Vert x_t \Vert}$in $\Vert r \frac{x_s}{\Vert x_s \Vert}-r \frac{x_t}{\Vert x_t \Vert} \Vert$

Comment: I detailed the proof. The key element is that $(\Vert x_n \Vert)$ is a Cauchy sequence of reals. Hence converges.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I do suggest an edit however. In the inequality, there are $s$'s that should be $t$'s. It causes the need for the last line to be altered.

Answer (score 1):

Quote form the Wikipedia: "... a normed vector space is a vector space over the **real** or **complex** numbers..."

Hint for the solution to the problem:
$X\backslash\{0\} = \{tx:t > 0,x\in S_r\}$.

Comment: Oh you're correct. I've mistakenly missed that completely. I have not clue then how to proceed. However thank you for pointing out my mistake.